# How to adding .wsdl file to c# project in visual studio

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio

and i will adding it to my project.This wsdl filee is not on online,
it's a file in my computer.

After adding this file to my project I will use it such as a web service
how can i do it itried some methods after looking google but nothing i.e :
[Adding WSDL files from file directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674271/adding-wsdl-files-from-file-directory)

that wsdl file must import to my project directory such as other files in my projects.

Comment: Open *"Developer command prompt for VS2..."* and type *wsdl.exe* or *svcutil.exe*

Comment: thank for your command,it created .cs file from .wsdl file