# How to use services Defined in WSDL file using C# code Behind ( Asp Web Forms )?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, wsdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302525/how-to-use-a-wsdl)

1 - User will fill the form in one website page and press submit (http://www.vivointernet.com.br/ )
2 - The submit calls a function (that need to be developed in this job) that created a xml file (wsdl format) that is the file attached (BlenderServices.xml)
3 - You need to use the method EnviarMailing (already on BlenderServices.xml). The parameters "campanha" value is "SiteVivo" and the other parameters (nome(name), email, endereco(address), telefone(phone) and so on) you will get from form and save on that BlenderService.wsdl format.

So, basically the format is already defined. Is the BlenderService.wsdl format. What I need to do is to write the functions that will call it when user press submit and pass the parameters.
And save that information in attached xml format....
//here is BlendServices.xml file....

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46576111/BlenderServices.wsdl

Kindly tell what services are mentioned in file and How I can use these services using C#..
I am Newbie to Webservices but knows the architecture but not C# code......

Comment: So, you are basically asking "How do I write code to call a web service?"

Comment: Yes Jmret i am asking to write a code to call a web service using C# which is on attached .wsdl file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try visiting this page:  [How to use a WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302525/how-to-use-a-wsdl) 
This explains the basics of using a WSDL with C#.

Comment: Thanks Jmrent ......Actually I  need to use the method EnviarMailing (already on BlenderServices.wsdl) using C# by passing three parameters which will come from form.....

Comment: Follow the directions in the link that I posted above.  What this will do is create for you an object that you can use to call the web service.  It is pretty straight forward.  Is there some additional information that you need that is not provided in the link?

Comment: Thanks I have Got What I want from your Directions