# The underlying connection was closed - WEB SERVICES

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, api

I wanna connect with API through Web Services

I've done everything like this:
[Integration with another system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337939/integration-with-another-system/25338125#25338125)

and I get the same error:
**"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."**

I also created a new class:

```
Class MyTestService
    Inherits SenditAPI.SendItpl
    Protected Overrides Function GetWebRequest(ByVal uri As Uri) As System.Net.WebRequest
        Dim webRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        webRequest = CType(MyBase.GetWebRequest(uri), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
        'Setting KeepAlive to false 
        webRequest.KeepAlive = False
        GetWebRequest = webRequest
    End Function
End Class
```

according with http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with configuration.

Check **App.config** file. The address in `<value>...</value>` seems to be incorrect.