# Unable to create service reference for wsdl file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I have `wsdl` file and `xsd` files at my local machine. I want to add service reference in project. I don't have web service I only have `wsdl` file.

I'm getting the following error:

```
The document was understood, but it could not be processed.
  - The WSDL document contains links that could not be resolved.
  - There was an error downloading 'http://localhost/DService/AllService.svc?xsd=xsd0'.
  - The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Edit the WSDL to link to the XSD files in the same directory on disk, instead of through an HTTP URL.

Comment: XSD schema location is this in wsdl<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/DService/AllService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>

Comment: Yeah, so remove the `http://localhost...` part.

Comment: like this schemaLocation="/DService/AllService.svc?xsd=xsd0" or

Comment: No, like `schemaLocation="XsdFile0.xsd"`.

Comment: thanks a lot gr8 help CodeCaster

Answer (score 2):

Your setup is complete with a wsdl file and a couple of xsd files. 
The reason you're having that problem is because the link `'http://localhost/DService/AllService.svc?xsd=xsd0'.` is broken.

The solution is to search the folder that has the xsd files for `AllService` . 
To make it easier, place all the files in a single folder. Next is that you copy the absolute path to the file that contain the search phrase `AllService`, replace the localhost url with the absolute path to the file.

Run the command again and watch it work.

Note: Do not remove the url as this is essential in making your complete proxy.