# Webservices WSDL file

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I'm newbie in C# web application. And now i'm stuck in web services.
My agency developed our company website and DB is located in France. but my company isn't there. 
This website have contact form.

My agency in France sent me .wsdl file. I want to get data from this contact form. It's about name, address and save it to local database.

Comment: so you just add this wsdl file as "SERVICE REFERENCE" in your solution, then you will able to call function from this wsdl file to get name, address etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply, so can you link me some example? thank you so much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302525/how-to-use-a-wsdl

Comment: thanks, i'm working on it, but I have a question to ask. Do we need database information such as, database server, userid and password to use wsdl? thank you so much

Comment: if those info is in their database, you just need to call the function and get those value you need. The wsdl file already prepared all for you.