# Consuming WSDL file C#

Tags: c#, wsdl

I have a WSDL file and I want to consume that.
I have added the reference of that file in a window application `ServiceReference1`.
Now there are two different classed one for `request` and another for `response`. I am not getting any method inside the `request` or `response` class.

Can any one guide me is there any thing I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302525/how-to-use-a-wsdl ?

Comment: @RahulTripathi thanks but I am not getting any method inside that.

Comment: You mean you are not able to get the methods inside the WSDL?

Comment: @RahulTripathi yes

Answer (score 0):

Don't look for the methods in the request or response. Look for them in the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to get the methods of the Soap client like

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
var method = type.GetMethod("yourMethodName");
var attr = method.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WebMethodAttribute), true);
```

Look at the [SoapExtension Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) and the article: [Efficient Tracing Using SOAP Extensions in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34381/Efficient-Tracing-Using-SOAP-Extensions-in-NET)

Also you can look at [WebServiceStudio](http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/)

> Web Service Studio is a tool to invoke webmethods interactively. The
>   user can provide a WSDL endpoint. On clicking button Get the tool
>   fetches the WSDL, generates .NET proxy from the WSDL and displays the
>   list of methods available.