# c# SOAP web service Complex type

Tags: c#, soap

I am new to SOAP complex type web services. I attached down here the wsdl file.
My question is
how to consume the web service? I mean how to call and how to call the callback function.

if possible, use the below wsdl and give me an example with c#
wsdl here
[wsdl here][1]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cEM0h3AO6tj1aDv6Z2BGfZUxEiQe9c9O

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302525/how-to-use-a-wsdl

Comment: Also please tell us what framework version, language version, and Visual Studio version you are using.

Comment: I have to use VS 2008 , c# language

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know to consume a SOAP API is to create a C# project and add a [service reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx).

[image]

Then add the address of your website and Visual Studio will generate a proxy for your WebService.

[image]

You will be able to call it in your project (Website/ConsoleApp).

You can have a sample of how to call the client when you call the svc of your WebSite if you use WCF.

ex: `http://<host>[/route]/<name of svc>.svc`

Comment: thanks for reply but i need to know how to serialize the complex object and pass it to the  web service either in client or server side

Comment: With a proxy, just instantiate the object and pass it to the method. On client side, with ajax, you need to create the xml and post it as the payload.